# How to terminate the inprogress api service call while angular route changes

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my application dashboard and multiple pages are available, for dashboard page calling multiple api services to get the reports, while loading the dashboard page user clicks the other page link, so that route changes though the dashboard related api call is executing.

Is there any mechanism to stop the api service call in angular.

like jquery xhr.abort().

Comment: which router are you ousing `(ui.router or ngRouter) ` and which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple subscriptions in your component, you might consider using a package that handles automatically unsubscribing for you, e.g. [ngx-auto-unsubscribe](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe).

```
// import auto unsubscribe library
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from "ngx-auto-unsubscribe";

@AutoUnsubscribe() // this decorator will handle automatically unsubscribing for your
@Component({
  selector: 'inbox'
})
export class InboxComponent {
  one: Subscription;
  two: Subscription; // etc.

  constructor( private store: Store<any>, private element : ElementRef ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.one = store.select("data").subscribe(data => // do something);
    this.two = Observable.interval.subscribe(data => // do something);
  }

  // If you work with AOT this method must be present, even if empty! 
  // Otherwise 'ng build --prod' will optimize away any calls to ngOnDestroy, 
  // even if the method is added by the @AutoUnsubscribe decorator
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // You can also do whatever you need here
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the it's the same approach and author whose link I've added in my answer. I'd personally avoid installing a package and add a decorator in my code. Cheers !

Comment: if you only have one call/subscription in your component, I wouldn't suggest installing a package to handle unsubscribing. if you have a lot of subscriptions, it can be quite handy to use a package which handles unsubscribing for you to avoid writing boilerplate code. :)

Answer (score 0):

For angular (not angular JS),
You can use `unsubscribe` for canceling API calls. Assuming you are using subscriptions, you can use Angular life cycle hook `ngOnDestroy` to cancel the request.

```
ngOnDestroy() {

  this.subscription.unsubscribe();

}
```

You can even move in the advance direction and create a custom decorator which allows you to automatically unsubscribe from all the subscriptions. So you can avoid repetition of `ngOnDestroy` in component.

Refer [Automagically Unsubscribe in Angular](https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88)

Comment: For .NET Core for example, does this also send a CancellationToken? Or does unsubscribe only ignore the result?

Comment: I have used multiple services , is this ok this.serive1.unsubscribe();this.serive2.unsubscribe();this.serive3.unsubscribe();

Comment: @Govindaraj Yes.The simplest thing to do would be unsubscribing from every subscription. It will avoid memory leaks. There are advance ways to unsubscribe as well for ex. using decorators. Check the updated answer.